# Solidity Hardhattesting for a function

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

How to write a hardhat test for this

Version

"hardhat": "^2.17.0",
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"ethers": "^6.6.4",

smartcontract function:

```
 function purchaseNFT(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
            uint256 price = tokenIdToMarketItem[tokenId].price;
            require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the correct purchase price to complete the transaction");
            tokenIdToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(address(0));
            tokenIdToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = true;
            _itemsSold.increment();
            _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
            payable(tokenIdToMarketItem[tokenId].seller).transfer(msg.value);
        }
```

how to make a test case for this function ? can anyone give idea

I tried to make a testcase but it shows mul is not a function so how to write test case for this function purchase NFT?

```
it("Should allow a user to purchase an NFT from the marketplace", async function () {
  const nftURI = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYP96XCnv2GnCJhvbty8U7VL1QpJUkfQC51zzRih8McT8/7705305.jpg";
 const listingPrice = ethers.parseEther("0.1");
   await nftMarketplace.createAndListNFT(nftURI, listingPrice);

  const tokenId = 1;
  const initialSellerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(marketplaceOwner.address);

  const purchaseTx = await nftMarketplace.connect(buyer).purchaseNFT(tokenId, { value: listingPrice });
  await purchaseTx.wait();

  const updatedSellerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(marketplaceOwner.address);

  const gasPrice = purchaseTx.gasPrice;
  const gasUsed = (await purchaseTx.wait()).gasUsed;
  const gasCost = gasPrice.mul(gasUsed);
  const expectedSellerBalanceInWei = initialSellerBalance.sub(gasCost).add(listingPrice);

  expect(updatedSellerBalance.toString()).to.equal(expectedSellerBalanceInWei.toString());
  const ownerOfNFT = await nftMarketplace.ownerOf(tokenId);
  expect(ownerOfNFT).to.equal(buyer.address);
  const isSold = await nftMarketplace.tokenIdToMarketItem(tokenId);
  expect(isSold.sold).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explicitly calculate the transaction fee. You can do something like this

```
await expect(await nftMarketplace.connect(buyer).purchaseNFT(tokenId, { value: listingPrice })
).to.changeEtherBalance(seller, listingPricing);
```

If you want to use transaction fee too then you can use this https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#change-ether-balance, apart from that there are so many issues with your code, such as after setting the seller address to address(0) you are doing a transfer at the end, you are trying to check the change in balance of the seller including the transaction fee but the buyer is doing the transaction over here not the seller.